# C#: Debug.Assert() with complex condition

Tags: c#, .net, assert

I'm writing a library where internally it uses a `ConcurrentQueue`. In one of the `private` method, I want to make sure that the item that I currently have is the item that will be dequeued (i.e. if I did not write my codes wrongly, this should be the expected behavior). How do I assert this correctly?

My current attempt is:

```
#if DEBUG
    object peeked = null;
    queue.TryPeek(out peeked);
    Debug.Assert(peeked == itemThatWillBeDequeued);
#endif
```

Which looks rather weird to me - if I need to use `#if` directive, then I wouldn't have used `Debug.Assert()`. However, there is no way I could directly place that `ConcurrentQueue.TryPeek()` into the assert statement inlinely either. Furthermore, doing that inline would probably mean that `ConcurrentQueue.TryPeek()` would run in release at runtime (unless I'm mistaken).

What should be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Write unit tests instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid the extra method suggested by Bacon, you could use a LINQ expression:

```
Debug.Assert(((Func<object>)(() => {
    object peeked;
    return queue.TryPeek(out peeked) ? peeked : null;
}))() == itemThatWillBeDequeued);
```

Explanation: `((Func<object>)(() => { ... }))` will create a function object from the enclosed code. The `()` will execute this function and return its result.

Comment: I wonder how the compiler handles the anonymous function. Will it compile in a release build?

Comment: No, it will not be compiled in Release. Just checked it with ildasm.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it too, it indeed does seems like it doesn't get compiled.

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap the call in a method

```
Debug.Assert(itemThatWillBeDequeued.equals(PeekQueue(queue)));
```

...

```
static object PeekQueue(ConcurrentQueue queue)
{
  object peeked = null;
  queue.TryPeek(out peeked);
  return peeked;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the method `PeekQueue` be compiled in release builds?

Comment: sure, but not executed